# Appending string print output

Tags: python, string, function

I want to find word in sentence to give a category to sentence. For that I have created a function listed below:

```
def theme(x):
    category = ()
    for i in x:
        if 'AC' in i:
            category = 'AC problem'
        elif 'insects' in i:
            category = 'Cleanliness'
        elif 'clean' in i:
            category = 'Cleanliness'
        elif 'food' in i:
            category = 'Food Problem'
        elif 'delay' in i:
            category = 'Train Delayed'
        else:
            category = 'None'
        print(category)
```

the output is :

```
None
None
AC problem
None
AC problem
```

How should I save this output to a variable

Comment: what is input and what should be data type of your output variable?

Comment: input are sentences: 1. everything is ok 2. it is too dirty, 3. AC not working, insects in boggy, ac not cooling. Output should be categories defined in function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def theme(x):

    category = []

    for i in x:
        if 'AC' in i:
            category.append('AC problem')
        elif 'insects' in i:
            category.append('Cleanliness')
        elif 'clean' in i:
            category.append('Cleanliness')
        elif 'food' in i:
            category.append('Food Problem')
        elif 'delay' in i:
            category.append('Train Delayed')
        else:
            category.append('None')

    return category

categories = theme(['bla bla AC bla','bla insects bla'])
print(categories)
```

Comment: instead of using repeated 'if' for a category how can i iterate thru a list. For e.g.: if category AC problem = ['AC', 'ac', 'fan'] and if any of these words are in sentence i get category AC problem

Comment: @anantsaxena if there are only a few, combine with `or`: `if 'AC' in i or 'fan' in i`

Answer (score 2):

```
def theme(x):
    output =[]
    category = ()
    for i in x:
        if 'AC' in i:
            category = 'AC problem'
        elif 'insects' in i:
            category = 'Cleanliness'
        elif 'clean' in i:
            category = 'Cleanliness'
        elif 'food' in i:
            category = 'Food Problem'
        elif 'delay' in i:
            category = 'Train Delayed'
        else:
            category = 'None'
        output.append(category)
    return output
```

Comment: @anantsaxena how did you call the function?

Comment: theme(text data)

Comment: You should call it like `result = theme(text data)`. Otherwise you are  ignoring the function return value.

Comment: @progmatico it is not returning any output

Comment: Are you passing a single sentence string when you call it?

Comment: @progmatico no i am passing a series of five sentences.

Comment: It should work then. Just call it and print result or whatever name you assign the theme call to.